# ¿Qué código es el de la tecla "Fin" en el teclado virtual?

Tags: java, android, teclado

Estoy haciendo esta aplicación y me gustaría saber cual es el código de la tecla "Fin" que aparece abajo a la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He encontrad esta tabla de códigos: (https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices) en ella se encuentra la tecla KEY_END con el android code KEYCODE_MOVE_END. ¿Podría ser?

Comment: que propiedad estas definiendo:  android:imeOptions= ?

Comment: Gracias, ya lo resolví, resulto ser que era el KEYCODE_ENTER, que se ve que cambia de nombre dependiendo del teclado, porque probé en otro y salia un símbolo de check y es el mismo código.